# Hovering over the Documentation recent users produces inaccurate information

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, review-queues

Observed this while mousing over the Documentation recent reviewers.

[image]

Doesn't seem to occur on any of the other queues.

Comment: TIL about review stats when hovering...

Comment: @JarrodDixon:  Honestly, me too...but y'know, new feature and all...

Comment: That feature was always there (I guess!?!). I've seen that long back.

Comment: The Closey creators knew about this way back...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next build should fix this, which is rolling out now.

Thank you!